# My wallet is empty and I get this strange repeating message when running Ether in the Terminal

Tags: wallets

I was looking for a way to speed up the part where it said "X Months since last block", and found the answer here (moving from WiFi to cable)

One of the tips was booting the ETH command in the Nodes/eth/max-x64 folder.

I booted that Etc command, and now I get this message:
(It keeps repeating this message too, every few seconds)

```
  ✘  12:58:31.244|txcheck0  Bad transaction: /Users/travis/build/bobsummerwill/cpp-ethereum/libethcore/Transaction.cpp(76): Throw in function dev::eth::TransactionBase::TransactionBase(bytesConstRef, dev::eth::CheckTransaction)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<dev::eth::InvalidSignature>
std::exception::what: InvalidSignature
[dev::eth::tag_field*] = 8
[dev::eth::tag_data*] = 9f7d3d0ec40b4d50f9a5cdf5da311d7ae68a7c0f52eaf4da79ad3f359f19eb2f
[dev::eth::tag_field*] = invalid transaction format
```

I think it's weird that I no longer have any ether (I should have had some left on that account). So before I buy new ETH, I'd like to find out if this isn't some virus sucking my account dry.

Comment: You would do well mentioning OS version, full name of the wallet software and its version. It also seems you haven't used it in a while, it's taking a long time to sync, so you're trying to short-circuit it by running some command (which one?..).

Answer (score 1):

Check the account hash in your wallet when `eth` is running.  It's probably not the same account that's usually in your wallet, but a new, empty one.

Quit the wallet app, stop `eth` from running, and run your wallet app again.  That should make your Ethers re-appear.  Then, be patient, get some coffee, and let the wallet sync. :)
[image: screenshot of Ethereum wallet showing account hash]

### What's going on

The Ethereum wallet app runs an embedded client (`geth` by default) if it doesn't find another client already running.  This client stores its data in a specific format in a platform-dependent location (e.g. `~/Library/Ethereum` on the Mac).

When you run `eth`, you're starting a *different* ethereum client on your system. It will store its data and sync a *different* copy of the blockchain in a different format in a different location (e.g. `~/.ethereum` on the Mac).

When you then run your Ethereum wallet, it will see that a client is running (your `eth` client) and will connect to it.  Since this client's database is different than the one your app was using before, it doesn't have your account (or even the synced blockchain).  So, the wallet makes a nice new account for you with no Ether in it.  If you don't carefully examine the account hash, it can just look like you don't have any Ether.
The error messages are most likely the result of the blockchain sync, but aren't related to your account.